# Creating a Layer Group in GeoServer with Python

Tags: python, geoserver, xml, request

I am trying to create a Layer Group in Python using the Request module, but I am getting an HTTP 406 (Not Acceptable) error.

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code?

```
import requests

layerGroupURL = 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/OS_OpenData/layergroups'

auth = ('admin', '******')

layerGroupXML = '''
                <layerGroup>
                    <name>Road_Group</name>
                    <mode>SINGLE</mode>
                    <title>Road_Group</title>
                    <workspace>
                        <name>OS_OpenData</name>
                    </workspace>
                    <publishables>
                        <published type="layer">
                        <name>OS_OpenData:oro_roadlink_201910</name>
                        <atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="alternate" href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/OS_OpenData/layers/oro_roadlink_201910.xml" type="application/xml"/>
                    </published>
                        <published type="layer">
                        <name>OS_OpenData:oro_roadnode_201910</name>
                        <atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="alternate" href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/OS_OpenData/layers/oro_roadnode_201910.xml" type="application/xml"/>
                        </published>
                    </publishables>
                    <styles>
                        <style>
                            <name>oro_RoadLink-1</name>
                            <atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="alternate" href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/styles/oro_RoadLink-1.xml" type="application/xml"/>
                            </style>
                        <style>
                            <name>oro_RoadNode</name>
                            <atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="alternate" href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/styles/oro_RoadNode.xml" type="application/xml"/>
                        </style>
                    </styles>
                    <bounds>
                        <minx>-118397.00155160861</minx>
                        <maxx>751441.7791101651</maxx>
                        <miny>-15982.135610342928</miny>
                        <maxy>1272149.3463547546</maxy>
                        <crs class="projected">EPSG:27700</crs>
                    </bounds>
                    <attribution>
                        <logoWidth>0</logoWidth>
                        <logoHeight>0</logoHeight>
                    </attribution>
                </layerGroup>
            '''
headers = {'Content-type': 'text/xml', 'Accept': 'text/xml'}

layerGroupRequestPost = requests.post(url=layerGroupURL, auth=auth, data=layerGroupXML, headers=headers)

print(layerGroupRequestPost.status_code)
```

Comment: what does the GeoServer log file say? probably need to turn it up to developer to be sure

Comment: The log is say: 2019-10-21 14:19:13,323 WARN [annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver] - Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The acceptable types for this type of transaction are listed in [the manual](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/api/#/latest/en/api/1.0.0/layergroups.yaml) as `application/xml` and `application/json` not `text/xml` as you are using.

Comment: Thank You! That work!